# Design Stock Server Application in C++

Tags: c++

[Queston asked in ML Interview]

Design an server/application which handle multiple incoming stock information ( stock symbol and values ) Server need to store the information in some cache ( need to design the data structure ), There are multiple client connected to server using tcp/ip socket. They will subscribe to particular request say stock symbol XYZ , and may be for more then one. As and when there is change the stock symbol server should broadcast the information to subscribed client. If tcp/ip write failed, server should handle the unregistration of the client.

What various data structures will be used and how threading model will be ?

Comment: Oops my bad I should have read ML interview

Comment: The last thing finance industry needs is IT people who do not know what they are doing.

Comment: It was very similar to what was asked to me in a Bbg Interview hence :).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a n-tier messaging kind of scenario have a look at this [pubsub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe),

Comment: will this model scale like more than 10000 of requests 1 second

Comment: @Avinash it is used in major stock exchanges and major trading systems, It is the basis for most of the message brokers including JMS, Apache Active MQ, and I dont know for sure but twitter seems to be based on a similar paradigm

but yes write it and see :)

Comment: anijhaw, the link you have given says literally this `scalability for pub/sub products under high load in large deployments is very much a research challenge`. So it is not quite obvious how good this approach scales.

Comment: @Skwllsp, if you scroll down the page you would see the part where it says Middleware implementing pub/sub, almost all of the industry standard message broker systems implement this protocol but yes it isnt simple :)

Answer (score 0):

This is asked in bloomberg or sell side first for designing question interview.

http://anandpandia.blogspot.com/2012/08/merge-sort-algorithm-and-example-in-c.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.